# How to reduce memory usage on DolphinDB nodes?

Tags: memory, memory-management, dolphindb

I found that a large amount of memory is consumed by my data nodes, even though there are no jobs running.

Does anyone know the possible causes of this problem? And I would greatly appreciate it if someone could share some best practices for how to release the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To diagnose and solve the problem, refer to the following steps:

1. Call `getSessionMemoryStat` to check the memory usage in your data
   nodes.
2. Use `objs` to inspect if there are any variables that have not been
   released.